# Writing to Azure SQL Database from PHP application

Tags: php

I would like to know if it's possible to write directly to an azure sql database from a PHP form within an application.

So for example I could have a 3 field form with something like "ID", "Name", "Email" and then on submit that would go straight into the database.

I know this is easily done with mySQL but I have a specific requirement for using Azure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you are using linux, you should :

[Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)

Then it's pretty straightforward :

```
<?php
    $serverName = "your_server.database.windows.net"; // update me
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "your_database", // update me
        "Uid" => "your_username", // update me
        "PWD" => "your_password" // update me
    );
    //Establishes the connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    $tsql= "SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName
         FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc
         JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p
         ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid";
    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    echo ("Reading data from table" . PHP_EOL);
    if ($getResults == FALSE)
        echo (sqlsrv_errors());
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo ($row['CategoryName'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . PHP_EOL);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
?>
```

[Full Documentation for MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-php)

[Full Documentation for PHP SQLSRV functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php)